# Upgrade Odoo from V8 to V10

Tags: migration, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

We want to upgrade Odoo V8.0 to V10. Currently, we have Odoo V8.0 installed from git hub source code on centos.

Now We have to upgrade our current V8.0 to V10, with my current running database and the current running database should not corrupt.
How can I upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336830/how-to-upgrade-odoo-8-to-odoo-9-database/33345268#33345268) I have suggested two options for upgrading your database.

Comment: so need to upgrade one step upgradation like odoo version 8 to 9,
then upgrade odoo 9 to 10 right ?

Comment: Best way is to export data from your v8 database and import it in v10 database from pgadmin. I know this will consume lot of time but that's the easiest way.

Comment: Use select * from your_table and use export option in the menu for exporting so that you can import it in v10 db

Answer (score 0):

There is [OpenUpgrade](https://github.com/OCA/OpenUpgrade/issues/1036) by OCA that you can try, but it is not ready for 10.0 yet unfortunately.

I'd probably manually export-import models, I don't think that there is a much easier way to this.

Answer (score 0):

You just installed V10 of Odoo in your system. For migrating database to V8 to V10 check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27935745/backup-odoo-db-from-within-odoo/46090153#46090153).